# ignore files in a specific repository

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have an app running on heroku, which I versioning on github too. But there are some files that I don't need to put on github (s3 configuration, mongoid configuration, etc), but I do need them on heroku.
How do I ignore these files only on github but do not ignore on heroku (without have to use another branch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this file containing API keys? In this case you can use [Heroku's environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), it's the best practice I know to secure your API keys.

Comment: yes, i'm using api keys. i'll take a look into it. thanks. I will accept this answers for now, until someone provide an explanation for the git exclude